# Overload >.. operator for function that creates Range excluding first index and includes last index does not work

Tags: swift, function

I want to create global function that creates range. It will be analog for the ..> function. But I cannot do that. XCode shows me a lot of errors when I introduce him this code

```
infix operator >.. {
    associativity none
    precedence 135 
}
```

```
@warn_unused_result
    func >..<Pos : ForwardIndexType where Pos : Comparable>(start: Pos, end: Pos) -> Range<Pos> {
    return Range(start: start.successor(), end: end)
}
```

It shows me strange errors that try to change my syntax.
Exception: when I change operator to *** for example - it works. But this operator is not good for this case of function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

The Swift compiler that is part of Xcode 7.2 only allows an operator to contain dots if it either contains only dots (minimum two) or is exactly `..<`. See [`swift/Lexer.cpp`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c99c02b5a63212076939f532b6ec9a2b64fbfa2c/lib/Parse/Lexer.cpp#L595). [I opened a bug report about it.](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-605)

Then I investigated further and found that [Chris Lattner rewrote that part of the code on Dec 17, 2015](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/0bfacde2420937bfb6e0e1be6567b0e90ee2fb67) to be more flexible. Quoting the commit message:

> The policy is now very
>   simple: if an operator name starts with a dot, it is allowed to include other
>   dots in its name.  If it doesn't, it doesn't.

So expect some future version of Swift (not Xcode 7.3-beta, I checked) to allow you to define an operator that starts with dots and other doodads, but still not `>..`.

#### ORIGINAL

The only way to include dots in a Swift operator is to start the operator with two dots. Here's the relevant part of the Swift grammar:

> *operator* → *dot-operator-head* *­dot-operator-characters­<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *…snip…*
>   *dot-operator-head* → `..`­
>   *dot-operator-character* → `.`­ | *operator-character­*
>   *dot-operator-characters* → *dot-operator-character* *­dot-operator-characters­<sub>opt­</sub>*

Since `.` is not included in any other part of the operator grammar, you cannot include a `.` anywhere in an operator unless the operator begins with `..`.

You can find the full operator grammar in [*The Swift Programming Language*: “Operators”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID418).

Comment: As I understand the grammar, `..>` or `../` should be valid "dot operators", but they are not accepted. Did you find any valid operator that starts with `..` and does not consists entirely of dots? Did I overlook something in the grammar?